# Juju deployment with Openstack. Environment starts - instances not

Tags: 12.04, juju, openstack

I want to buld a juju deployment on an openstack cloud.
An environment type ec2 works, but i want to use the environment type openstack_s3, which does not work.

Hera are some details:

- Ubuntu 12.04 Server
- Openstack (without Swift) installed from the Ubuntu Repos.
- My environment:

```
juju: environments
default: s3
environments:
  s3:
    type: openstack_s3
    control-bucket: juju-...
    admin-secret: 1a15743cab5...
    combined-key: 6cfba71eec6...
    secret-key: d82e45f647074...
    ec2-uri: http://IP:8773/services/Cloud
    s3-uri: http://IP:3333
    default-series: precise
    default-image-id: fb2ba7a7...
    auth-url: http://IP:5000/v2.0/
    username: openstack user
    password: openstack user-pass
    project-name: openstack-project
```

The `juju bootstrap` is ok, the first instance started and I can ssh it. If I deploy a service, an new instance should be started but nothing happens in the Openstack Dashboard.

This is the output of `juju status`:

```
machines:
 0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: 192.168.X.X
    instance-id: ca659b15...
    instance-state: running
  1:
    instance-id: pending
services:
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:precise/wordpress-10
    relations:
      loadbalancer:
      - wordpress
    units:
      wordpress/0:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 1
        public-address: null
```

I got only this error in the provision-agent.log on the bootstrap-node, but it doesent helped me so far.

```
ubuntu@juju-s3-instance-0:~$ cat /var/log/juju/
machine-agent.log    provision-agent.log
ubuntu@juju-s3-instance-0:~$ cat /var/log/juju/provision-agent.log
2013-02-28 12:20:39,008: twisted@ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2013-02-28 12:20:39,115: twisted@ERROR: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 391, in errback
    self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 458, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 545, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1095, in gotResult
    _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
---  ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1037, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 382, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/agents/base.py", line 245, in startService
    yield self.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1037, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 382, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/agents/provision.py", line 36, in start
    self.environment = yield self.configure_environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1037, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 382, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/agents/provision.py", line 88, in configure_environment
    environment = yield watch_d
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1039, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/agents/provision.py", line 92, in configure_environment
    config.parse(environment_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/environment/config.py", line 138, in parse
    config = SCHEMA.coerce(config, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/lib/schema.py", line 266, in coerce
    new_dict[k] = self.schema[k].coerce(v, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/lib/schema.py", line 233, in coerce
    new_subvalue = self.value_schema.coerce(subvalue, value_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/lib/schema.py", line 301, in coerce
    return self.schemas[selected].coerce(value, path)
exceptions.KeyError: 'openstack_s3'
```

Can anyone give me an advice, where I can locate the problem?

Thank you!